# Rails 3: Different namespace inside nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

Is there a way to use a (different) namespaces inside nested resources? For example,
I have:

```
resources :users do
 resources :tags
end
```

and I'd like to place the tags controller inside controllers/common, while placing users controller inside controllers/user, with the equivalent for templates.

If I try this:

```
namespace :user do
 resources :users do
  namespace :common do
   resources :tags
  end 
 end
end
```

I'll get redundant route names:

**user_common_tags**, etc. But I want something like **common_tags**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you will have common_tags, and users_tags, both linking to the same controller.

```
resources :users do
  resources :tags
end

namespace :common do
  resources :tags
end
```