# Multiple namespace declaration in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have two namespaces, and they use the same resources, can I do the following?

```
namespace :captures, :displays do
  resources :ones
  resources :twos
  resources :threes
  # ...
end
```

instead of:

```
namespace :captures do
  resources :ones
  resources :twos
  resources :threes
  # ...
end

namespace :displays do
  resources :ones
  resources :twos
  resources :threes
  # ...
end
```

or are separate declarations neccessary.   I know if they end up have different resources they would have to be separat, but if I can declare the shared ones then I could do something like this:

```
#shared
namespace :captures, :displays do
  resources :ones
  resources :twos
  resources :threes
  # ...
end

#individual
namespace :captures do
  resources :fours
  resources :fives
  resources :sixes
end
namespace :displays do
  resources :sevens
  resources :eights
  resources :nines
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes separate declaration is necessary while using namespace in routes even if common resources are used.

Comment: you can refere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896339/rails-3-different-namespace-inside-nested-resource

Answer (score 10):

I came across this ticket while looking for a similar answer.  I solved this problem before like this:

```
%w[captures displays].each do |space|
  namespace space do
    resources :ones
    resources :twos
    resources :threes
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this - the second option in the namespace method is a hash.  The namespace method is just a shortcut for :path, module, and :as.  It won't do it for two namespaces in one call.

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass proc as a block to the namepace method like so:

```
duplicate_routes = -> do
  resources :ones
  resources :twos
end

namespace :captures, &duplicate_routes
namespace :displays, &duplicate_routes
duplicate_routes.call # use the same routes in root namespace
```